# Why doesn't Angular CLI project start?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an Angular 4 project that I created a couple of months ago. When I go into the Angular project folder and type in `ng serve`, I get this error:

> You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the serve
>   command.

Any idea what is wrong?

Is there some specific file that I can verify is there?

As a side note, I create a `ng new Folder2` and was able to successfully run `ng serve` in that folder.

Comment: is your project built with `angular cli` ? if so, do you have file `.angular-cli.json` in a project folder? Otherwise you might be running the `ng serve`  command from the wrong folder.

Comment: Please post how your folder tree looks like

Comment: go down another level dude, you at the parent folder

Comment: `.angular-cli.json` is there. Going down another level (outside of the project) didn't help.

Comment: did your `.angular-cli.json` has `"apps": [ ]` property declared and what is your cli version on a project?

Comment: Yes - `"apps": [ ]` is there. angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3, node: 8.0.0

Comment: Is your folder small enough to zip it and share?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me it is seems like as you didn't touch the project for so long you might have an older version of the `angular cli` in you project than your global version or way around.

if you run `ng -v` outside your project it show you global cli version
if you run `ng -v` inside your project it will show you local cli version, also you can check the cli version in `package.json` in `devDependencies`

So you have two options.
1 update `angular cli`
2 run `npm run ng serve` this way npm will run the local `angular cli`, the one form `package.json` file

Comment: Outside of the project folder: angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3, node: 8.0.0. Inside the project folder is the same but I also have this output: @angular/cli: 1.0.3, which is the same version coming from package.json.

Comment: `angular-cli` is an old package you need to get rid of this. then run` npm install @angular/cli -g` to install the latest version.

Comment: Running `npm run serve` throws this error: `npm ERR! missing script: serve`.

Comment: btw `npm run ng serve` that the right command to run local cli, sorry :)